# How can i create users in ubuntu to have full premissions in only the apache www folder?

Tags: php, sftp

I am creating a remote dev environment for my team on a large EC2 in AWS.

Each member which have their own folder in the www directory in Apache and i want them to have full access rights inside that folders for their own development /deployment but not access each others development folders / outside of their folder

How can i create these accounts and set up their user name / passwords and their own ssh key to access the server and only use / have full access rights inside that folder?

Also i want to disable FTP / SFTP on these folders for all users?

Comment: If you got one instance of apache a developer could pivot reading the other users files though php, you wont be able to stop that.. imo, LXD/LXC containers would be much better solution as each developer has there own vm, then use nginx as a reverse proxy to forward web, and iptables to forward tcp traffic like ssh, you also got things like ngrok which they can ssh/web into

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

- create users, with their primary group being the same as their user name.
- Add the apache user in each users' group.
- Create one directory per user
- Set the permissions to `rwxr-x---`

Ex:

```
user1:user1  
user2:user2
```

`apache` is member of groups `user1` and `user2`

```
drwxr-x---  user1  user1  [...]/htdocs/user1_files
drwxr-x---  user2  user2  [...]/htdocs/user2_files
```

This way users only see their own directory, and the apache user has access to all to use the files.

For your FTP question, it depends what FTP you use.  If it is just a basic FTP server, you cannot block access, without turning it off.  Users would only be able to write to their own directory anyway.

If your FTP software is a bit more evolved, you may be able to control permissions in it through configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that,  for FTP we don't need it at all. they use git to pull down the data so it's to limit FTP or SFTP from puling down sensitive data.

They only need HTTP, and SSH protocols.

Comment: Try it out, if it works for you, I would appreciate the check on the answer :-)

Comment: would you be able to give me a little more detail in the commands for the above, im not a pro on linux.

Comment: There are plenty info on the web.  Look for details on adduser, addgroup, chmod, chown, mkdir.  Do you have an admin close by?

Comment: Na we are a start up :)

Comment: i added a user but i can't log in with the user, when i type in the user name it gives me a key error, do i need to give the user permission to log in somehow?